# why npm run build file is not working when deploy to firebase?

Tags: firebase, npm, build

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB9a9VB823uFu4c5EW6r3C1BI-YzpZlR70",
  authDomain: "furniture-management-fab4b.firebaseapp.com",
  projectid: "furniture-management-fab4b",
  storageBucket: "furniture-management-fab4b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderid: "898675896450",
  appid: "1:898675896450:web:fadd09253871b2d934849b",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Specifically_, what does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].